# Mongo running in linux container, stop taking connection.

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, docker

I am running MongoDB inside the Docker, a linux container. Based on this [Dockerfile](http://dockerfile.github.io/#/mongodb).

I am using the latest mongo release, 2.6.4 installed on Ubuntu 14.04 64bits. I am able to start the `mongod`, I do have a `/data/db` folder in the container and the host machine ( even used as mounted folder, it is there in host machine. ). Do have enough memory, but I was getting errors.

From the logs below, you could clear tell that I am trying to connect the `db` twice, the connection won't be open for some reasons. Someone could help me?

Note: the machine only have `git` and `mongo` installed. Do mongo need anything else as dependencies?

```
2014-09-04T05:14:50.645+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=f00d8205ca65

2014-09-04T05:14:50.645+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4

2014-09-04T05:14:50.645+0000 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910

2014-09-04T05:14:50.645+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49

2014-09-04T05:14:50.645+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc

2014-09-04T05:14:50.646+0000 [initandlisten] options: {}

2014-09-04T05:14:50.648+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal

2014-09-04T05:14:50.648+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed

2014-09-04T05:14:50.703+0000 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.ns, filling with zeroes...

2014-09-04T05:14:50.703+0000 [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/db/_tmp

2014-09-04T05:14:50.705+0000 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0 secs

2014-09-04T05:14:50.708+0000 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.0, filling with zeroes...

2014-09-04T05:14:50.709+0000 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.001 secs

2014-09-04T05:14:50.711+0000 [initandlisten] build index on: local.startup_log properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "local.startup_log" }

2014-09-04T05:14:50.711+0000 [initandlisten]     added index to empty collection

2014-09-04T05:14:50.712+0000 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

2014-09-04T05:15:50.721+0000 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:36 virt:341

2014-09-04T05:15:50.721+0000 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):160

2014-09-04T05:15:50.721+0000 [clientcursormon]  connections:0

2014-09-04T05:15:57.976+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.17.42.1:56593 #1 (1 connection now open)

2014-09-04T05:15:57.976+0000 [conn1] end connection 172.17.42.1:56593 (0 connections now open)
```

Someone said it could be less memory to run mongo. after running the momery check, I do still have a good amount of memory to run Mongo.

```
[ root@512ea0e1096b:/data ]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2001        436       1564          0         24        276
-/+ buffers/cache:        136       1865
Swap:         2991          0       2991
```

Comment: Not sure whats going wrong. Can you start your mongod with --smallfiles option "mongod --smallfiles" and then try connecting to it. Also, please add how you are starting and connecting to mongo.

Comment: @LalitAgarwal: he did explain how he starts mongo,it is written in the description of the Dockerfile ;)

Comment: @MMA: Do you use Boot2Docker?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Ah, I see. My Bad!! thanks for pointing it out. I didn't check the link.

Comment: @LalitAgarwal @MarkusWMahlberg  I use `vagrant` to kick out a VirtrualBox VM running Ubuntu 14.04. I know `Boot2Docker` is the binary which recommend by Docker team, but I found vagrant is closer to the true VM. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you are a Docker, Vagrant user, you could see my local environment [here](https://github.com/mattma/docker-images)